# Getting ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<LoginCubit> above this BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState> Widget)

Tags: flutter, dart

This application was working fine until I started to add in support for routing, using this AppRouter class I wrote to handle onGenerateRoute from main.dart.

I created a Map of routes (strings) to Map<Widget, Cubit> in an attempt to make the getRoute() function really generic, however it's not working and throwing the exception whenever it tries to load the LoginPage.

```
class AppRouter {
  static const String homepageRoute = '/';
  static const String loginRoute = '/login';
  static const String prospectsRoute = '/prospects';

  static Map<String, Map<Widget, Cubit>> get _pageMap => {
    loginRoute: { const LoginPage(): LoginCubit(locator.get<LoginRepository>()) },
    homepageRoute: { const HomePage(): HomePageCubit(locator.get<HomePageRepository>()) },
    prospectsRoute: { const ProspectsPage(): ProspectsCubit(locator.get<ProspectsRepository>()) }
  };

  static Route generateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings){
    return getRoute(routeSettings.name!);
  }

  static Route getRoute(String name){
    final pageMap = _pageMap[name];

    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
        create: (create) => pageMap.values.first,
        child: pageMap!.keys.first
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my main application in main.dart (I've commented out the MultiBlocProvider because that's how I originally implemented this solution but I don't like it. It would be creating providers for every page, even if those pages were never used?):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return MultiBlocProvider(
    //   providers: [
    //     // BlocProvider<ProspectsCubit>(create: (context) => ProspectsCubit(locator.get<ProspectsRepository>())),
    //     // BlocProvider<LoginCubit>(create: (context) => LoginCubit(locator.get<LoginRepository>())),
    //     // BlocProvider<HomePageCubit>(create: (context) => HomePageCubit(locator.get<HomePageRepository>()))
    //   ], 
    //   child: 
      return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: const [ AppLocalizationsDelegate() ],
        onGenerateTitle: (context) => AppLocalizations.of(context).appTitle, // Can't use title property because of i18n
        onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: (AppTheme.darkAccent)),
          useMaterial3: true,
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            backgroundColor: AppTheme.dark,
            elevation: 0
          ),
        ),
        initialRoute: Credentials.isAuthenticated ? AppRouter.homepageRoute : AppRouter.loginRoute,
      //)
    );
  }
}
```

You can see specifically where I use the onGenerateRoute property and call AppRouter.generateRoute:

```
 onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
```

Here is the output / stack trace of the error:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  LoginPage
  LoginPage:file:///C:/Users/source/repos/[redacted]/lib/router.dart:21:25

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3  throw_
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 343:7                                    _inheritedElementOf
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 293:30                                   of
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 649:21                                   ReadContext.read
```

It appears to be crashing on this line in router.dart:

```
loginRoute: { const LoginPage(): LoginCubit(locator.get<LoginRepository>()) },
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should provide the LoginCubit above the root tree or above where you are using it using BlocProvider.

Comment: So if my app has 10 pages, I need to add all 10 cubits into the main.dart file in MultiBlocProvider ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Wow, that's ugly. No way to put the cubits inside each page so main.dart doesn't have to know about all of them? or is there any way to do it inside AppRouter like I have it?

Comment: You should add it only once in the root of the project.

Comment: Look at this example: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/15#issuecomment-439587979

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just put all my Cubits inside a MultiBlocProvider in main.dart and just going to do it that way. I was hoping to keep all of those references out of my main app.